# Why isn't the "constraint trick" working in this manually defined HasField instance?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, typechecking

I have this (admittedly weird) code which uses [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) and [GHC.Records](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Records.html):

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, PolyKinds, FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
module Main where
import Control.Lens
import GHC.Records 

data Glass r = Glass -- just a dumb proxy

class Glassy r where
  the :: Glass r

instance Glassy x where
  the = Glass

instance (HasField k r v, x ~ r)
-- instance (HasField k r v, Glass x ~ Glass r) 
  => HasField k (Glass x) (ReifiedGetter r v) where
  getField _ = Getter (to (getField @k))

data Person = Person { name :: String, age :: Int } 

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn $ Person "foo" 0 ^. runGetter (getField @"name" the)
```

The idea is having a [`HasField`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/GHC-Records.html#t:HasField) instance that conjures [`ReifiedGetter`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.19.1/docs/Control-Lens-Reified.html#t:ReifiedGetter)s out of a proxy, just for the hell of it. But it isn't working:

```
* Ambiguous type variable `r0' arising from a use of `getField'
  prevents the constraint `(HasField
                              "name"
                              (Glass r0)
                              (ReifiedGetter Person [Char]))' from being solved.
```

I don't understand why `r0` remains ambiguous. I used the [constraint trick](https://chrisdone.com/posts/haskell-constraint-trick/), and my intuition is that the instance head should match, then the typechecker would find `r0 ~ Person` in the preconditions, and that would remove the ambiguity.

If I change `(HasField k r v, x ~ r)` into  `(HasField k r v, Glass x ~ Glass r)` that removes the ambiguity and it compiles fine. But why does it work, and why doesn't it work the other way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, it had to do with `Glass` being poly-kinded:

```
*Main> :kind! Glass
Glass :: k -> *
```

Meanwhile, unlike the type parameter of `Glass`, the "record" in `HasField` has to be of kind `Type`:

```
*Main> :set -XPolyKinds
*Main> import GHC.Records
*Main GHC.Records> :kind HasField
HasField :: k -> * -> * -> Constraint
```

If I add a standalone kind signature like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneKindSignatures #-}
import Data.Kind (Type)
type Glass :: Type -> Type
data Glass r = Glass
```

then it typechecks even with `(HasField k r v, x ~ r)`.

---

In fact, with the kind signature, the "constraint trick" ceases to be necessary:

```
instance HasField k r v => HasField k (Glass r) (ReifiedGetter r v) where
  getField _ = Getter (to (getField @k))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ Person "foo" 0 ^. runGetter (getField @"name" the)
  print $ Person "foo" 0 ^. runGetter (getField @"age" the)
```

Here, the flow of information during typechecking seems to be:

- We know we have a `Person`, so—through `runGetter`—the field's type in the `HasField` must be `ReifiedGetter Person v` and the `r` must be `Person`.
- Because `r` is `Person`, the source type in the `HasField` must be `Glass Person`. We can now resolve the trivial `Glassy` instance for the `the`.
- The key `k` in the `HasField` is given as a type literal: the `Symbol` `name`.
- We check the instance preconditions. We know `k` and `r`, and they jointly determine `v` because of the `HasField` functional dependency. The instance exists (automagically generated for record types) and now we know that `v` is `String`. We have successfully disambiguated all types.